# How can I get the opposite value of a float/int in Android?

Tags: android, scroll

i got the following method on my class:

```
@Override  
public void onScrollProgressChanged(float progress) {

    MyView.animate().alpha(progress);

}
```

the progress move from 0 to 1.0f and vice-versa. Is there any way i can obatin a float value of 0 when the progress is at 1.0f? and of course while it's scrolling i need to obtain the opposite value always so that 0.2 have to be 0.8.

Thank you

Comment: (1.0 - progress) ? If it's the relative opposite value use -(Math.abs(progress))

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer you find useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
float opposite = 1 - progress;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
private float mFloat;
@Override  
public void onScrollProgressChanged(float progress) {

    MyView.animate().alpha(progress);
    mFloat = 1 - progress;
}
```